# difficulties with handling big matrices in c++

Tags: c++, matrix, segmentation-fault

I try to work with a - not even tooooo - colossal matrix in C++ but there seems to be a memory problem and I could need some help.

The following code compiles without a warning with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -o matrix main.cpp`
But when I want to run it, I get the following message: `zsh: segmentation fault  ./matrix`
My compiler version is: Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)

```
#define HEIGHT 0x1000
#define WIDTH 0x1000
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main () {
    int hexVal = 0x0;
    std::array<std::array<int, HEIGHT>, WIDTH > matrix;
    //std::vector< std::vector<int> > matrix (HEIGHT*WIDTH);

    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = hexVal;
            hexVal++;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "your matrix is living here: " << &matrix << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried the same with `std::vector`, but no matter what I do, I always get this error when running: `zsh: segmentation fault  ./matrix`

At least when using `std::array`, it helps to change the size of the matrix but unfortunately this is not an option.

```
#define HEIGHT 0x100
#define WIDTH 0x100
```

works just fine.

Interestingly though the following also worked,

```
#define HEIGHT 0x100
#define WIDTH 0x1000
```

but the below didn't.

```
#define HEIGHT 0x1000
#define WIDTH 0x100
```

I have read a little on segmentation fault and came to the conclusion that it could be a hardware defect but at this point I still don't want to believe that. I hope, some stackoverflow magic can help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It needs `4096 * 4096 * sizeof(int)` bytes on the stack - default stack is usually 1M

Comment: Shouldn't `matrix[i][j] = hexVal;` be `matrix[j][i] = hexVal;` since you are using column-major order?

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix (HEIGHT*WIDTH)` defines `matrix` as  `HEIGHT*WIDTH` empty vectors.

Comment: `std::array` is no more automatic-storage friendly than a native array; it simply affords you many of the luxuries that don't normally come with fixed arrays, but do come with standard library containers (assignment, for example, value arguments being another). In short, using `std::array<std::array<int, HEIGHT>, WIDTH>` is no more automatic-storage space friendly than `int ar[WIDTH][HEIGHT]`

Comment: @wcochran of course, you are absolutely right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of cause `std::array` is not suitable for VERY large matrix if you place it on stack, like you did. Stack is limited and sometimes it may be below 1MB in size.

Try using `std::vector` or allocate `std::array` on heap. Heap is not limited, it can grow almost up to size of whole RAM.

Next example is using `std::vector`, on my machine it doesn't crash.

Also notice how I define std::vector variable in my code, it is different to your definition.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/1q6o1Y)

```
#define HEIGHT 0x1000
#define WIDTH 0x1000
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main () {
    int hexVal = 0x0;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(HEIGHT, std::vector<int>(WIDTH));

    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = hexVal;
            hexVal++;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "your matrix is living here: " << &matrix << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
your matrix is living here: 000000D275CFFA28
```

As suggested by @WhozCraig it is also possible to use std::array as inner array, i.e. create matrix through:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/eWxGEv)

```
std::vector matrix(HEIGHT, std::array<int, WIDTH>{});
```

Comment: Optionally (and advisably), there is no reason for inferior dimension to be stored in a vector. I.e. depending on the use case it is entirely conceivable that `std::vector<std::array<int, WIDTH>> matrix(HEIGHT);` , e.g. a vector of arrays, will deliver better performance, both at allocation time and cache-hit friendliness. That obviously goes south the moment the inferior dimension is no longer constant.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it must've been something simple. I just have allocated the memory in a wrong way, when using `std::vector`

Comment: @RandomGuy If my answer was correct and/or helpful please Accept and/or UpVote it. Accepting and UpVoting is done at the top of my answer to the left from it. There is Check-Mark for accepting as correct answer and Upper-Arrow for up-voting. Also see end of my answer, I just updated it to use std::array too.

Comment: @Arty thank you for the update. I actually upvotes your answer immediately but my reputation is less than 15 and it seems that such votes cast by users like me are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.